# Cordova iOS plugins not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I recently upgraded to Cordova 2.9.0 from 2.3.0. After following all the upgrade instructions, I was able to get the app to launch in the simulator. However, in Xcode I see the following errors:

```
ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["Device1776032119","Device","getDeviceInfo",[]]
ERROR: Plugin 'NetworkStatus' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["NetworkStatus1776032120","NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo",[]]
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","Logger","logLevel",["LOG","deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds."]]
ERROR: Plugin 'Logger' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","Logger","logLevel",["LOG","Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady"]]
ERROR: Plugin 'Logger' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","Logger","logLevel",["LOG","Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady"]]
```

This is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVBattery" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Echo">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVEcho" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Logger">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <access origin="*.googleapis.com"/>
    <access origin="*.gstatic.com"/>
    <access origin="*.s3.amazonaws.com"/>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 31):

For future searchers (like me!), I had a similar problem trying to add the console plugin to my project. The missing step for me after installing the plugin was to make sure the source files of the plugin (CDVlogger.m) 'target membership' settings included my application names.

Comment: I'm curious what could cause plugin files not to have 'Target membership' checked. I looked at plugin.xml files for other plugins that do have it, and there's nothing different I can see.

Comment: I'm building several apps from the same code, so I created multiple targets in the xcode project. Only the default target created initially had the files in their membership. So my cordova commands didn't know about them.  I confess I didn't look deeper into config.json, or something like it, to see if there was a way for me handle multiple targets in the xcode project.  But adding them manually in xcode was a simple fix.

Comment: Something similar worked for me: "In XCode, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin .m file." from http://stackoverflow.com/a/21148428/80254

Comment: Your solution actually does the same, but is more convenient.

Comment: Here is the [issue on Cordova's bug tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5454). I have traced and debugged this issue. See [comments here for explanation and work around](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5454?focusedCommentId=14498888&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14498888). This is an issue with node-xcode, for which I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/alunny/node-xcode/issues/44) and [pull request](https://github.com/alunny/node-xcode/pull/45), which is accepted.

Answer (score 26):

Similar question with answer that worked for me:

> remove ./plugins/ios.json  to make sure the plugins are rebuilt.

[Phonegap 3.0 IOS plugins not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403225/phonegap-3-0-ios-plugins-not-found)

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you..!

Comment: Helped! `cordova: ^8.0.0` `cordova-ios: ^4.5.5`

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue.  I just downloaded the cordova 3.0 command line tool using node's package manager.  I then used the tool from Terminal to create my project, add platforms to it, and build it like this.

```
cordova create myApp com.project.RobertW myApp
cd myApp
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
cordova build
```

After this I saw those same errors in Xcode when I tried to run it in the simulator.  It seems by default now PhoneGap does not include any plugins in the project so even if there in your config file they probably won't be in the plugins folder.  You have to add them manually or via the command line tool.  I used the command line tool because I thought it was easier like so.

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git
cordova build
```

After doing this I ran myApp in the simulator again and everything worked fine. There are some good instructions on the command line tool here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

I would like to think if PhoneGap 3.0 needs Logger, Device, and Network Status that it would include those plugins automatically but in my case it did not.  Hope this helps.

Edit:  In the config.xml for iOS version in Xcode, you'll also need to make this change to get the Logger plugin to work correctly. The following is the default.

```
<feature name="Console">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
</feature>
```

Change above to this

```
<feature name="Logger">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
</feature>
```

Now all your console functions should work without throwing errors.

Comment: Hi all, I just had the same issue with CDVDevice. The only way that worked was to create a new project, re-add the plugins as shown, and then the existing code in the www folder. Then it worked again (yay).

Comment: I have solved the issue (which came up when I updated cordova 6.0.0 -> 6.1.1) by removing the ios platform and adding it again. Try that before creating a new project.

Comment: It works for me as my console.log is the key issue for me to have a blank screen.  Thanks, Hugo

Comment: Thanks!! In my case add names in the config.xml for iOS version in Xcode:
CDVDevice, CDVStatusBar, CDVFile, CDVSplashScreen

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue with the device information plugin using Phonegap 3.0.0. To solve this I simply had to uninstall and reinstall the plugin and then rebuild my project.

```
phonegap local plugin remove org.apache.cordova.device
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
phonegap local build ios
```

Comment: Using cordova, uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

I went back to using the old `<plugin>` format. Although it is deprecated, it's the only way that works for me.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
    <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
    ...
</plugins>
```

Comment: Heh, I always find it easier to set up a new project every time I use a new version of Phonegap, and copy my file back in. Just my preference.

Comment: I did the same, but deprecation messages realllllly bug the hell out of me. So frustrating.

Comment: I did the same and it worked for the facebook connect plugin:<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />

Answer (score 3):

In my case...the solution was add this line of code for all plugin that i use.. in my config.xml

```
    <feature name="Device">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>

<feature name="FCMPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FCMPlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>

<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>

<feature name="CDVLocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>

<feature name="cordova.logger">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>

<feature name="Logger">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>

<feature name="Console">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>


<feature name="SQLitePlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="SQLitePlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>

  <feature name="Keyboard">
    <param name="ios-package" value="IonicKeyboard" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

Comment: This solution only work on my case. I have some plugins that added manually, and this solves my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Came across this issue myself.  Found the only solution was running `cordova prepare` after adding the plugins via CLI.  `prepare` copies the necessary files across to the XCode project within the `platforms` folder.

I think this should be done as part of the `build` command, or the `plugin add` command if the project is present.  Maybe it's a bug, maybe it's deliberate, but I couldn't find much documentation on it.

[Similar question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447827/ios-unable-to-find-plugins-android-fine).

Answer (score 2):

happened to me on phonegap 3.5 with Xcode 6

steps:

```
phonegap plugin remove org.apache.cordova.camera 
phongap plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera 
phongap platform remove ios
phongap build ios
```

Probably not the best solution - because you lose your xcode settings - But it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. I simply created the directory myself (platforms/ios/appname/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.console) and copied the missing files (CDVLLogger.h and CDVLLogger.m) to this directory. Then the compilation went through successfully.

I am using cordova version 3.5

Comment: where do you get those files from?

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error using Ionic then trying running `cordova run ios --device` instead of `ionic run ios --device` It fixed the issue for me. I think the Ionic cli v2 was messing things up since the project was an Ionic 1 project. I had no issues before updating the Ionic cli.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem with the SQLitePlugin. I tried some of the proposed solutions in this post but none of them exactly worked for me. Then I tried to remove the platform/ios dir (I am developing for an iPhone), added the ios platform again (ionic add platform ios) and rebuilt the project. Suddenly, everything worked like a charm. I didn't had to create a new project nor had to remove the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

We opened the project in Xcode, and looked in the ***Project navigator*** sidebar.

Under the virtual "Plugins" folder we noticed that the files for some plugins were missing from this folder.

[image: the Plugins folder in the sidebar containing a few plugin files]

The solution was to right-click on ***Plugins*** and select ***Add Files to "ProjectName"...***

Then we navigated into the plugin's folder and added all the `.swift` and `.m` and `.h` files there.

Doing this created new references in the file `platforms/ios/[ProjectName].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` so we kept those changes.

Answer (score 0):

For new cordova versions

**Mass Saving of Plugins on an Existing Project**

If you have a pre-existing project and you want to save all currently added plugins in the project, you can use:

```
cordova plugin save
```