# Phonegap 3.0.0 - Facebook SDK 3.6 - FB plugin: Facebook connect not found

Tags: ios, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I'm having this problem with Phonegap 3.0.0 and their Facebook plugin. I followed their explanation to the letter (two times), and i'm beginning to think that either I'm doing something stupendously wrong, or my versions don't line up properly.

The error I get from both the hackbook and simple.html is:

```
ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

So according to everything I found online (which in this case is not a whole lot seeing they made some mayor changes in recent versions), it seems to do with either my plist or xml.

So I was hoping somebody has gotten it running already, or knows what I'm doing wrong.

As for the config.xml, i'm using the one in the www folder (is that the correct one?), and added:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="[app_id]" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="[app_name]" />
</gap:plugin>
```

As for the plist I ended up adding:

```
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>[app_name]</string>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>[app_id]</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>[app_name]</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb[app_id]</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The rest is done as stated in the tutorial of the github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure for this specific plugin but recently Phonegap has started using this format in the config.xml

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

I installed this from the command line using their command line tool.  I was in the root directory(one above the www directory, here I have the plugins, www,platforms, and merges folder), and I run the following command.

```
 phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

Not sure if this applies to plugins not listed on PhoneGaps documentation page but you could try this with the Facebook Connect plugin and change the url to the url of the Facebook connect's git repo.  If it works the command line tool should update the config.xml and everything else as needed. Hope this helps but as I said, I haven't tried the facebook plugin but I had a similar issue with other out of the box plugins and this is how I resolved those.

Edit:

Here is the url from another thread I answered with a similar issue with a different plugin. Just look for my response.
[Cordova iOS plugins not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384523/cordova-ios-plugins-not-found/18007571#18007571)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But i'm afraid no cookie for you :)
As of 3.0 it is not yet a downloadable plugin it seems. So no automated systems unfortunately. I'll just wait until they update the fb github page to fit 3.0 or automate the plugin.

Comment: Ahh, I had a feeling that might be the case.  Im sure they'll update it soon. There is probably a setting somewhere that needs to be adjusted for it to work correctly. Maybe try changing the param name.  Where it says `ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found`  its expecting the "org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" to be your plugin name, try changing your config.xml to this and see if this helps `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="[app_id]" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="[app_name]" />
</gap:plugin>`

Comment: The "<feature" you sent in works like a charm. I don't know how everybody else does it with 3.0, but mine posts stuff like a boss.
Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The plugin is not compatible yet wit v3.0, the convertion in config.xml (not the www/config.xml, but the root directory's config.xml) from  to  is like this:

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Comment: your answer already obsolete since. Even he put this code into config.xml, it will generate an error like in his question.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having the same problem and was only editing the www/config.xml without any progress.

Answer (score 1):

Latest answer for latest facebook phonegap plugin. @Geykel's answer already deprecated according to this issue.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/issues/20

Make sure you include your FacebookConnectPlugin.m inside Compile Sources

Build Phases > Compile Phases

[image]