# phonegap 3.0 facebook login

Tags: facebook, authentication, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I m using phonegap 3.0 and trying to install the below faceook login plugin:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

I have added the following changes in the config.xml file

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="[APP_ID]" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="[APP_NAME]" />
```

But still when i am trying to install the plugin its giving me the following error:
Error: Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME

Can anyone tell me why this error might be occuring.M i missing adding any changes in some file.
Thanks

Comment: Ok, silly question, but did you put your app_id and app_name in where it says [APP_ID] and [APP_NAME]. Forgive me, but sometimes it is the silly things that get me so I figured it cant hurt to ask.

Comment: hi @Dom that is just as a reference.I have entered my actuall APP_ID and Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this plugin hasn't been rewritten for phonegap 3.x yet. Here is the issue on the github project where people are discussing it: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/343

And here is where someone fixed the android part of the code to work with phonegap 3.x: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/pull/348

Also, here is where someone else was having trouble using it for iOS with phonegap 3.x: [Phonegap 3.0.0 - Facebook SDK 3.6 - FB plugin: Facebook connect not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113128/phonegap-3-0-0-facebook-sdk-3-6-fb-plugin-facebook-connect-not-found)

On the instructions in the plugin readme it says:

6) Replace your appId in the new index.html file. Leave the quotes.

You can look in the examples folder and you'll see something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    try {
        alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
        FB.init({ appId: "appid", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}, false);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Plugin should be fully CLI compatible now on master branch.

Here is some sample code

`cordova create myApp
cd myApp/
cordova platform add ios
cordova -d plugin add /Users/your/path/here/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"`

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too. Here answer https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/issues/21