# iOS unable to find plugins, Android fine

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am building an app in Phonegap/Cordova.  App is fairly simple at the moment, but does require the network status and geolocation plugins to work.

I've developed the app so far (it's made up of just a few basic HTML pages and a bit of JS at the moment) on Android and it has been working fine.

This morning I decided to make sure all was well with iOS.  To absolutely no surprise at all, it isn't.

So... it appears to be a problem with the plugins.  XCode spits out the following:

```
CDVPlugin class CDVLocation (pluginName: Geolocation) does not exist.
2013-10-18 11:24:29.437 Eye Cab[589:907] ERROR: Plugin 'Geolocation' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-10-18 11:24:29.438 Eye Cab[589:907] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 117] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "Geolocation1841912763",
  "Geolocation",
  "getLocation",
  [
    false,
    0
  ]
]
```

I guess this means it can't load the Geolocation plugin.  I get a similar thing for the network connection plugin.

Below is my truncated config.xml from the Phonegap project:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
</feature>
```

I have also tried using the IDs as the feature name (eg. org.apache.cordova.geolocation), but get the same problem.  The exact same error in fact.

Everything works perfectly in Android; in the simulator, in Chrome on my mac and on a device.

I am using the following versions:

- Phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0
- XCode 5.0
- OSX 10.8.5
- iOS 6.1.3 (iPod Touch)
- iOS Simulator for iOS 7

The correct files are in the /www/plugins/ folder in the project:

- org.apache.cordova.geolocation

  - www

    - Coordinates.js
    - Position.js
    - PositionError.js
    - geolocation.js
- org.apache.cordova.network-information

  - www

    - Connection.js
    - network.js

An elated hug for anyone who can help with this.  I've trawled through the other questions but with no luck.

Comment: this may be related to a known cordova bug discussed here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4971 . in short, plugins can apparently not always be added after a ios project has once been prepared. the solutions below are the best sofar.

Comment: You may also check a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668747/visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-ios-remotebuild-omitting-plugins-fo/35057129#35057129) that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS was missing the plugin files themselves (.m and .h files), which must be copied by calling `cordova prepare` or `phonegap prepare`.  Not very well documented it seems.

Comment: For future searchers: This solution didn't work for me and I don't understand how it could work - `cordova prepare` is included in `cordova build` (`build` is shorthand for `prepare` and `compile`). See my answer for a link to what did work for me.

Comment: Just to add to this, Mark's answer work for me but this one did not. There's some kind of issue with compiling the plugins for ios it seems...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. This definitely works for me and the docs have now been updated to include the cordova commands (cordova build incorporates cordova prepare). I guess there are a few potential pitfalls though, and these are just two of them. Glad its sorted for you anyway

Answer (score 60):

Mark's solution works but is unnecessary and will cause you to lose customizations to your XCode project.

What fixed it for me was:

In XCode, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin .m file that should be in your Plugins directory (but is missing from the compiled sources).

Comment: +1000 How you can have the file in your project but XCode will not compile it is beyond me.

Comment: There would be no .m file under the Plugins directory if iOS build cannot bring in the plugins.

Comment: In my case I forgot to run `cordova build ios` after resetting the project

Answer (score 31):

For future searchers - the solution that worked for me came from another stack overflow response, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19501579/1245276

In short: 
1. delete ./plugins/ios.json,
2. then delete ./platforms/ios, 
3. then run `cordova platform add ios` 
4. then `cordova build`. 
Deleting ios.json helps to force it to recompile the plugins, at least thats what I understand and it worked for me.

Comment: Removing `plugins/ios.json` is a key ingredient!

Comment: why do I keep seeing cordova in answers when my command line tool is phonegap ?

Comment: isnt this effectively the same as saying `cordova platform remove ios; cordova platform add ios;` ?

Comment: @commonpike Yes it is. There's no need to manually delete `./plugins/ios.json` and `./platforms/ios/`. Simply run `cordova platform remove ios`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was unable to find Plugin_name.m file in the plugins directory as well, so i manually added the Plugin_name.m file in build phases (you can find Plugin_name.m file in plugin->src->ios folder) and then copy the feature name of plugin from ios.json file (which is present in cordova-builds folder) and add it to config.xml file(remove back-slashes).
Plugin will work fine.

Note:- You may have to add all the files in build phases which is included in plugin_name.m file.