# cordova 3.4 file 1.0.1 resolveLocalFileSystemURI android issue

Tags: file-transfer, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get a full path to an image retrieved from Android image library. via the camera plugin.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("content://media/external/images/media/83", function(fileEntry) {
```

or

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
        newimageURI = fileObj.fullPath;
        alert(newimageURI);
    });
});
```

returns undefined.

There was updates the other day and it is no longer working. I have tried `toURL()` as well with no success.

Comment: I am having the same issue. `resolveLocalFileSystemURI` is defined for android but not ios

Comment: When it was originally working it wouldn't work on IOS but in may case that didn't matter as IOS could fine the path to both images from camera or gallery. but Android I need the fullpath for an image from the gallery. which I still can't get.

Comment: Do manage to solve this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the file plugin and adding it again. Works for me. I think it's related to this bug: [Cordova iOS Plugins fail after building, unless I remove platform and plugin JSON first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326504/cordova-ios-plugins-fail-after-building-unless-i-remove-platform-and-plugin-jso)

Comment: I've removed and added in the plugins multiple times but still doesn't work. I might try a clean project with just the basic code to see if I can get further with it.