# Phonegap Get App Version return null

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to get my application version and show it on the screen.

I added this plugin to my `config.xml` and then I used PhoneGap 3.3 for building `.ipa` and `.apk` file.

```
<gap:plugin name="net.bgta.phonegap.plugin.appversion" version="1.1.1" />
```

Then inside `onDeviceReady` I added this code to get `AppVersion`:

```
getAppVersion(function (version) {
    alert('Native App Version: ' + version);
});
```

But "version" always returns as `null`. Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you share your config.xml? Have you tried building your project locally?

Comment: yes, i already build my app locally and i get error : getAppVersion is undefined. And this is my config.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <description>DevExtreme based multiplatform application.  </description>

        

        <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>

        <access origin="*"/>

  <gap:plugin name="net.bgta.phonegap.plugin.appversion" version="1.1.1" />

Comment: Did you add the plugin to your project? `phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/rromerogar/net.bgta.phonegap.appversion.git` You can use `phonegap local plugin list` to make sure the plugin was installed.

Comment: Hello Sherb, thank you for helping me. But i use Visual Studio with Devextreme for building my app, so i don't have a way to add plugin like that, i just add this Plugin in my config.xml like that : <gap:plugin name="net.bgta.phonegap.plugin.appversion" version="1.1.1" />

Comment: Hm...i found out, only on iOS it return null, on Android its okay, i will post this issue on git, thank you for your helping Sherb !

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version/issues/14) in GitHub about this. The workaround suggested is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326504/cordova-ios-plugins-fail-after-building-unless-i-remove-platform-and-plugin-jso/23934028#23934028):

> In XCode, go to **Build Phases**. Open the **Compiled Sources** dropdown.
>   Click + and add the missing `AppVersion.m` file that should be in your
>   Plugins directory (but is missing from the compiled sources).