# Check internet connection on iOS app with Cordova Phonegap 3.3.0 not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, connection

I have tried following [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#The%20Command-Line%0AInterface) guide on Cordova docs, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

I have added `<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />` to `config.xml`.

and this script to my `index.html`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert("1"); // runs this alert
            checkConnection();
        }

        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = Connection.CELL;
            alert("2"); // doesn't run this

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        }

    </script>
```

`var networkState = Connection.CELL;` seems to cause the problem as it doesn't run the following alert, I have also tried `navigator.connection.type` but the same thing happened.

When I run the app in Chrome the console outputs the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Connection is not defined
```

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Cheers

Comment: Have you included `Cordova.js` in your `index.html` file

Comment: Yes I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**I finally solved the problem!!** - by starting all over again from scratch and doing the following:

Command line:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add ios
cordova platforms ls //This will list ios
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
cordova build
```

Then drag my files (HTML, Javascript etc) into the `platforms/ios/www/` folder.

Open up `hello.xcodeproj` in xcode.

Edit config.xml and add the lines:

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
</feature>
```

Then in my index file I used the JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        // device APIs are available
        function onDeviceReady() {
            if(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
                alert("nocon");
            }else{
                alert("yescon");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Then run it in the iPhone / iPad simulator and it will output "yescon" if there is a connection and "nocon" if there isn't!!

Hope this helps!

Comment: a simpler approach, without the need to start from scratch - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19688926/126600

Comment: not working I am using ios7 and cordova 3.3 used connection.CELL

Comment: I haven't used connection.CELL, I checked to see if there was a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have included your Cordova.js file in html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And change `App/Supporting Files/Cordova.plist` of your project.

```
<key>Plugins</key>
     <dict>
     <key>NetworkStatus</key>
     <string>CDVConnection</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Cordova.plist was discontinued and was replaced my config.xml, the code above does basically the same as the plugin code

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
if(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
//no connection
}else{
//You are connected.
}
```

Though I look in the documentation and looks like there's a difference using these lines:

`var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;`

navigator.network.connection.type is set to `Connection.CELL_2G` for all cellular data.

Would it be `var networkState = Connection.CELL_2G;`?

Comment: I have tried it with navigator.network.connection.type, I think this is depreciated or doesn't work with iOS it says at the bottom of the Cordova Docs page (for 3.3.0) -
iOS Quirks

iOS can't detect the type of cellular network connection.
navigator.connection.type is set to Connection.CELL for all cellular data.

Comment: It says `Connection.CELL_2G`, I'm not sure if this will matter.

Comment: After rebuilding the app and copying over the www files, it still doesn't work.. when you said you got it working were you using cordova 3.3.0?

Comment: I'm using cordova 2.9.

Comment: hhmmm weird, I now have it outputting the error: `ERROR: Plugin 'NetworkStatus' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml` :(
I have this line in the config.xml `<feature name="NetworkStatus"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" /></feature>`
... so confused why this isn't working! The Cordova documentation is awful.. really need rewriting