# GeofencePlugin Cordova plugin not working for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Rest plugins are working fine may be this was written in swift(don't know) so i am getting below error continuously.

```
Plugin 'GeofencePlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

tried both below configuration in config.xml but no success

```
<feature name="Geofence">
        <param name="ios-package" value="HWPGeofencePlugin" />
</feature>

<feature name="Geofence">
   <param name="ios-package" value="cordova-plugin-geofence/HWPGeofencePlugin" />
</feature>
```

Tried

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21148428/80254 and many more links but not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: using https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence plugin for ios

Comment: how did you install the plugin?

Comment: using this command on terminal "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence"

Comment: which cordova version are you using? I've just tested with cordova CLI 5.1.1, cordova iOS 3.8.0 and it's working fine. You don't have to add anything to the config.xml, that's done automatically on plugin install, but not on the root config.xml, in the platforms/ios/ config.xml

Comment: i m using cordova ios 3.8.0 ,cordova cli 5.1.1, xcode 5 and iosx 10.8.4.

Comment: xcode 5 is the problem, the plugin has swift classes and I don't thing you can compile them from xcode 5

Comment: which xcode version you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved xcode 5 was the problem. thanks @jcesarmobile