# PhoneGap error: Plugin 'LowLatencyAudio' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We're using PhoneGap 3.4. We installed the LowLatencyAudio plugin, following the instructions here: https://github.com/triceam/LowLatencyAudio

However, we see the following error:

```
2014-03-10 19:59:25.960 S[7828:60b] CDVPlugin class LowLatencyAudio (pluginName: LowLatencyAudio) does not exist.
2014-03-10 19:59:25.962 S[7828:60b] ERROR: Plugin 'LowLatencyAudio' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-03-10 19:59:25.963 S[7828:60b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 127] FAILED pluginJSON = [
"INVALID",
"LowLatencyAudio",
"preloadFX",
[
"sounds\/right.mp3",
"sounds\/wrong.mp3"
]
]
```

the mapping does exist in config.xml. we invoke the code with:

```
LowLatencyAudio.preloadFX( GUESS_RIGHT_SOUND, GUESS_RIGHT_SOUND);
LowLatencyAudio.preloadFX( GUESS_WRONG_SOUND, GUESS_WRONG_SOUND);
```

we have also tried:

```
PGLowLatencyAudio.preloadFX( GUESS_RIGHT_SOUND, GUESS_RIGHT_SOUND);
PGLowLatencyAudio.preloadFX( GUESS_WRONG_SOUND, GUESS_WRONG_SOUND);
```

both approaches fail, and only the `LowLatencyAudio` one generates error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Cordova iOS plugins not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384523/cordova-ios-plugins-not-found)

Make sure the plugin source classes have their "target membership" include the right applications.