# Cordova / Phonegap oauth.io popup not showing

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, oauth

im developing a cordova webapp, actually i integrated the oauth.io API and i use a own server daemon to make it work.

When i try to login via socials on desktop browser it works like a charm, but when i try on ios simulator it wont work, it doesnt open the popup to connect via socials.

So i installed this https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap changed config.xml file to allow all origins in this way:

```
    .....
     <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

    <!-- Don't store local date in an iCloud backup. Turn this to "cloud" to enable storage
         to be sent to iCloud. Note: enabling this could result in Apple rejecting your app.
    -->
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
       <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
.....
```

I use ionicframework so my oauth code is javascript/angularjs as i can show here:

```
 .provider('OAuthd', function () {

    var theClientId = '';

    return {

      'setClientId': function(value) {
        theClientId = value;
      },
      '$get': ['$window', '$q', '$cacheFactory', function ($window, $q, $cacheFactory) {

        var cache = $cacheFactory('OAuthdProviderCache');
        ($window.OAuth.initialize || angular.noop)(theClientId);

        return {
          'facebook' : function() {

            var facebookAPI = cache.get('facebook')
              , deferred = $q.defer();

            if (!facebookAPI) {

              $window.OAuth.popup('facebook', function(err, result) {

                if (!err) {

                  deferred.resolve(result);
                } else {

                  deferred.reject(err);
                }
              });
              cache.put('facebook', deferred.promise);
              return deferred.promise;
            }

            return facebookAPI;
          },
          'twitter': function() {

            var twitterAPI = cache.get('twitter')
              , deferred = $q.defer();

            if (!twitterAPI) {

              $window.OAuth.popup('twitter', function(err, result) {

                if (!err) {

                  deferred.resolve(result);
                } else {

                  deferred.reject(err);
                }
              });
              cache.put('twitter', deferred.promise);
              return deferred.promise;
            }

            return twitterAPI;
          },
          'google': function() {

            var googlePlusAPI = cache.get('google_plus')
              , deferred = $q.defer();

            if (!googlePlusAPI) {

              $window.OAuth.popup('google_plus', function(err, result) {

                if (!err) {

                  deferred.resolve(result);
                } else {

                  deferred.reject(err);
                }
              });

              cache.put('google_plus', deferred.promise);
              return deferred.promise;
            }

            return googlePlusAPI;
          }
        };
      }]
    };
});
```

But it wont work anyway, do you have any clue?

thanks

this is what the cordova console.log returns everytime i try it on ios simulator or android simulator:

```
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.
2014-08-08 11:18:53.958 chatting[4573:70b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-08-08 11:18:53.971 chatting[4573:70b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-08-08 11:18:54.000 chatting[4573:70b] CDVPlugin class IonicKeyboard (pluginName: keyboard) does not exist.
2014-08-08 11:18:54.000 chatting[4573:70b] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.589967ms
2014-08-08 11:18:54.001 chatting[4573:70b] CDVPlugin class CDVStatusBar (pluginName: statusbar) does not exist.
2014-08-08 11:18:54.002 chatting[4573:70b] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 0.699997ms
2014-08-08 11:18:54.002 chatting[4573:70b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 2.420008ms
2014-08-08 11:18:54.351 chatting[4573:70b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-08-08 11:18:55.026 chatting[4573:70b] Finished load of: file:///Users/macuser/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181/chatting.app/www/index.html#/app/home
2014-08-08 11:18:55.274 chatting[4573:70b] CDVPlugin class IonicKeyboard (pluginName: Keyboard) does not exist.
2014-08-08 11:18:55.275 chatting[4573:70b] ERROR: Plugin 'Keyboard' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-08-08 11:18:55.275 chatting[4573:70b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "INVALID",
  "Keyboard",
  "hideKeyboardAccessoryBar",
  [
    true
  ]
]
2014-08-08 11:19:06.985 chatting[4573:70b] CDVPlugin class CDVInAppBrowser (pluginName: InAppBrowser) does not exist.
2014-08-08 11:19:06.985 chatting[4573:70b] ERROR: Plugin 'InAppBrowser' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-08-08 11:19:06.986 chatting[4573:70b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "InAppBrowser1514682083",
  "InAppBrowser",
  "open",
  [
    "http:\/\/auth.mysite.eu\/auth\/facebook?k=Jnpo3LK9wWrScy_cZ5xOQ5Fctx4&d=file%3A%2F%2F%2F&opts=%7B%22state%22%3A%222A9nV3-_ZBGs8HbZKVn_ffmy5MA%22%2C%22state_type%22%3A%22client%22%7D",
    "Authorization",
    "width=800,height=350,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=1,location=1,menuBar=0,left=-240,top=16.25"
  ]
]
2014-08-08 11:19:06.987 chatting[4573:70b] CDVPlugin class CDVLogger (pluginName: Console) does not exist.
2014-08-08 11:19:06.988 chatting[4573:70b] ERROR: Plugin 'Console' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-08-08 11:19:06.988 chatting[4573:70b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "INVALID",
  "Console",
  "logLevel",
  [
    "ERROR",
    "Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'wnd.focus()')\npopup@http:\/\/auth.mysite.eu\/download\/latest\/oauth.js:323:15\nfacebook@file:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support\/iPhone%20Simulator\/7.1\/Applications\/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181\/chatting.app\/www\/assets\/js\/providers.js:27:34\nsignup@file:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support\/iPhone%20Simulator\/7.1\/Applications\/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181\/chatting.app\/www\/assets\/js\/controllers.js:91:24\nfile:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support\/iPhone%20Simulator\/7.1\/Applications\/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181\/chatting.app\/www\/lib\/ionic\/js\/ionic.bundle.js:19654:26\nfile:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support\/iPhone%20Simulator\/7.1\/Applications\/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181\/chatting.app\/www\/lib\/ionic\/js\/ionic.bundle.js:42758:21\n$eval@file:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support[...]
2014-08-08 18:12:18.174 chatting[7825:70b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-08-08 18:12:31.794 chatting[7825:70b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-08-08 18:12:49.439 chatting[7825:70b] CDVPlugin class IonicKeyboard (pluginName: keyboard) does not exist.
2014-08-08 18:12:49.440 chatting[7825:70b] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.704050ms
2014-08-08 18:12:49.440 chatting[7825:70b] CDVPlugin class CDVStatusBar (pluginName: statusbar) does not exist.
2014-08-08 18:12:49.441 chatting[7825:70b] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 0.515997ms
2014-08-08 18:12:49.441 chatting[7825:70b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 2.322972ms
2014-08-08 18:12:54.431 chatting[7825:70b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-08-08 18:13:06.581 chatting[7825:70b] Finished load of: file:///Users/macuser/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181/chatting.app/www/index.html#/app/home
2014-08-08 18:13:08.127 chatting[7825:70b] CDVPlugin class IonicKeyboard (pluginName: Keyboard) does not exist.
2014-08-08 18:13:08.127 chatting[7825:70b] ERROR: Plugin 'Keyboard' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-08-08 18:13:08.127 chatting[7825:70b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "INVALID",
  "Keyboard",
  "hideKeyboardAccessoryBar",
  [
    true
  ]
]
2014-08-08 18:14:37.227 chatting[7825:70b] CDVPlugin class CDVInAppBrowser (pluginName: InAppBrowser) does not exist.
2014-08-08 18:14:37.228 chatting[7825:70b] ERROR: Plugin 'InAppBrowser' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-08-08 18:14:37.228 chatting[7825:70b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "InAppBrowser1564421013",
  "InAppBrowser",
  "open",
  [
    "http:\/\/auth.mysite.eu\/auth\/facebook?k=Jnpo3LK9wWrScy_cZ5xOQ5Fctx4&d=file%3A%2F%2F%2F&opts=%7B%22state%22%3A%226EG62ptFFZVSaIg2e2QCZXYx5Ak%22%2C%22state_type%22%3A%22client%22%7D",
    "Authorization",
    "width=800,height=350,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=1,location=1,menuBar=0,left=-240,top=16.25"
  ]
]
2014-08-08 18:14:37.229 chatting[7825:70b] CDVPlugin class CDVLogger (pluginName: Console) does not exist.
2014-08-08 18:14:37.229 chatting[7825:70b] ERROR: Plugin 'Console' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-08-08 18:14:37.229 chatting[7825:70b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "INVALID",
  "Console",
  "logLevel",
  [
    "ERROR",
    "Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'wnd.focus()')\npopup@http:\/\/auth.mysite.eu\/download\/latest\/oauth.js:323:15\nfacebook@file:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support\/iPhone%20Simulator\/7.1\/Applications\/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181\/chatting.app\/www\/assets\/js\/providers.js:27:34\nsignup@file:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support\/iPhone%20Simulator\/7.1\/Applications\/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181\/chatting.app\/www\/assets\/js\/controllers.js:91:24\nfile:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support\/iPhone%20Simulator\/7.1\/Applications\/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181\/chatting.app\/www\/lib\/ionic\/js\/ionic.bundle.js:19654:26\nfile:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support\/iPhone%20Simulator\/7.1\/Applications\/CA5E4763-35DA-44A3-A907-77E58E4CB181\/chatting.app\/www\/lib\/ionic\/js\/ionic.bundle.js:42758:21\n$eval@file:\/\/\/Users\/macuser\/Library\/Application%20Support[...]
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.
```

Comment: Could you show us your code using the OAuth.io Phonegap SDK? Also, do you have any errors showing up? You can use tools like Weinre (http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) to get a Google Chrome like console for Phonegap to get the errors.

Comment: @willjcksn i usually look into the platforms/ios/cordova/console.log file for errors and indeed there are few but errors inside, would you like to see them? i will attach them to the question (as you can see iposted the oAuth js code i use for opening popups)

Comment: @willjcksn check i updated the config.xml code tho

Comment: It seems like the InAppBrowser plugin, which is used to show the popup, is not found. It is normally installed when adding the OAuth.io plugin. To be sure, could you try installing InAppBrowser separately?

Comment: @willjcksn i removed and installed again the inAppBrowser plugin but still not working like if window.open is undefined :( i followed the cordova doc guide to install the inAppBrowser plugin :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem. This answer clued me in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576744/327458.

In XCode, I had to manually add CDVInAppBrowser.m to Build Phases / Compiled Sources.